# Was the Heart Donor purposely killed?

Tags: plot-explanation, vice

Dick Cheney was dying in the hospital and the doctor was telling the family that because there is no donor heart available that he will die and his wife said, "He's not going anywhere!" and the movie cuts to a scene where the man telling the story is killed and his heart used to save DC.  Does this mean that someone was targeted (by DC wife) and purposely run over to get a heart from a donor?  Someone please explain this scene to me.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

The death of the donor was purely accidental.

Mrs. Cheney statement that "He's not going anywhere" was just an expression of faith in her husband and his recovery and that somehow he would receive a heart.

Comment: I dunno man, hunting with Cheney is can be pretty dangerous, I wouldn't put it past them to do this.

Comment: If you're in need of a donor heart...running someone down with an truck is pretty poor way of going about it.

Comment: Well, yeah, there's the risk of crushing the chest cavity and damaging the heart. But we are talking about a guy that shot he hunting partner.